# What is a good way to interpret the performance results using python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have built an application, and now I have **already** run some performance tests (using pytest). With this I have already got enough data of CPU usage, memory usage, network usage etc. I also have done nice graphs with this.

By watching these graphs I can see intuitively some variance, some tendency etc. I can visually see that for example the CPU usage is below certain threshold, and that the tendency is kept constant. On the other hand if there is a tendency to increase I can visually infer that there is something wrong.

My question: What is a good way to measure analytically the performance based on this data?

I was thinking of using numpy to get the variance of the CPU usage, and the average to interpret numerically the results but then I realize that if I have data like this:

[image: Data with tendency to increase]

and take only average or variance, I wouldn't be able to detect the increase tendency.

Based on the data, how can I detect for example that the memory usage of the figure is increasing (revealing a possible memory leak)?

Would it be necessary to even use linear regression?

Comment: There is no general recipe. For data like you've shown, I'd chop off the first and last 10% of the data and do a linear fit. If the increase of the fitted function is greater than some threshold times the RMS residual, it counts as a significant growth.

Comment: linear fit? can I do that with pandas?

Comment: `np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)`

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys could you detail to me the part about the RMS residual? I suspect that could be the cause of my current problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533013/why-is-slope-not-a-good-measure-of-trends-for-data